Robinson Crusoe and his Olimpic Games
I have watched a movie about the story of Robinson Crusoe and Friday. Movie was about the Island Life but director directed the film dramatically. I can not remember movie exactly but Robinson Crusoe and Friday was playing Olimpic Games in a film section (running, javelin throw etc). Robinson was taking to the one coin (gold) to Friday for his helps and when Robinson had no coin, Friday wanted his freedom then he went his own clan in other island with canoe . In the end of the film, Robinson shot himself with old rifle. The film was  absolutely wonderful and dramatic but i can not remember the name. I watched film in CNBC-e Night Zone film series.
I hope someone know the films name.

Man Friday, (1975), with Peter O'Toole and Richard Roundtree.

After several years, Friday has accumulated 2,000 gold coins, the
  price that Crusoe once mockingly called for the hut and all his
  belongings. Friday now turns Crusoe's western ways against him.
  Catching him by surprise, he throws the gold on a table, declaring
  himself the owner of the material property; swiftly, he takes control
  of baffled Crusoe's gun, and coldly declares that the
  master-servant-relationship is inverted now. He forces Crusoe to build
  a solid raft, and both men put to sea for Friday's home island. When
  they have arrived there, Friday tells the story of their relationship
  to the gathered tribe, which reacts with astonishment and amusement
  about the strange ways of Crusoe. When the latter requests to join the
  tribe, proposing that he could teach the children, Friday strongly
  speaks against him, saying that "the only thing he (Crusoe) teaches is
  fear." So Crusoe is rejected and returns to his solitary island, where
  he commits suicide.

It isn't in the synopsis, but I do remember the Olympic Games as well.

Thanks a lot , hellalujah , after the 10 years i found the movie :)
